# MySQL. Selecting only a few data from one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, row

I have a question but I don't really know how to formulate it so I'll just show you.

I have this following table:

table1:

```
id | name | car | date_of_purchase | price
1    john   car1      date1           1000
2    andy   car2      date2            700
3    mike   car3      date3           3500
4    robb   car4      date4           2300
5    tony   car5      date5           1800
```

I know how to select the whole row but how can I select it by pieces?
For example from that table I want to get the row that contains the MAX of price, how can I do that?

```
name |  car  | max_price
mike    car3      3500
```

Comment: your desired output does not make sense since andy does not have a car with max price

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty You are right, I wasn't paying full attention, thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display your query results with arbitrary column headings.

```
SELECT t1.name AS name, t1.car AS car, t1.price AS max_price
    FROM table1 t1
    ORDER BY max_price DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this most easily with `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
order by price desc
limit 1;
```